# Testing window reload Redux reducer with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I have a reducer that returns `window.location.reload()`.  It is fired from an action creator that is called on a button click.

I am trying to mock this functionality up in Jest, and be able to test that in the reducer, a window reload is returned.  How do I mock this up efficiently?

I think this is a good topic to cover as testing a reload may be applicable in many other complex situations.  For mine, it may be as easy to not have this involved in Redux and just move it directly to the button `onClick()` property for the button React component (its React).

However, I would still like to know what the best way to mock window methods are in Jest, and others may as well.

Here's what I've got:

**Action**

```
export const cancelEdits = () => ({
    type: CANCEL_EDITS,
});
```

**Reducer**

```
case Actions.CANCEL_EDITS:
    return window.location.reload();
```

**Jest**

```
import * as Actions from "wherever";
it("should handle CANCEL_EDITS", () => {
    const action = { type: Actions.CANCEL_EDITS };
    const mockFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => window.location.reload());
    expect(commonReducer(state, action)).toEqual(mockFn);
});
```

I'm mocking the the action being fired within the reducer and then testing that it is equivalent to the Jest mock function, which returns a `window.location.reload()`

However, another option I have thought of is to mock up a store with `redux-mock-store` and have it dispatch the `cancelEdits()` action creator, which should fire the action, and then within the reducer test file, I would assert that the mockFn was called with like so:

`store.dispatch(Actions.cancelEdits())
 expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Not sure if this is a feasible way though.  I am also aware of the `jest.spyOn()` method but how would that be implemented?

Any info on this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Using [jest.fn(implementation)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) to create mocked methods and replace them on `window.location`

E.g.

`reducer.js`:

```js
import * as Actions from './actions';

export function commonReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.CANCEL_EDITS:
      return window.location.reload();
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`actions.js`:

```js
export const CANCEL_EDITS = 'CANCEL_EDITS';

export const cancelEdits = () => ({
  type: CANCEL_EDITS,
});
```

`reducer.test.js`:

```js
import { commonReducer } from './reducer';
import * as Actions from './actions';

describe('47704309', () => {
  it('should handle CANCEL_EDITS', () => {
    const state = {};
    const action = { type: Actions.CANCEL_EDITS };
    const mReload = jest.fn();
    window.location.reload = mReload;
    expect(commonReducer(state, action)).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(mReload).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should handle default case', () => {
    const state = {};
    const action = { type: '' };
    expect(commonReducer(state, action)).toEqual({});
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/47704309/reducer.test.js (8.958s)
  47704309
    ✓ should handle CANCEL_EDITS (6ms)
    ✓ should handle default case (1ms)

------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files   |     87.5 |      100 |       50 |      100 |                   |
 actions.js |    66.67 |      100 |        0 |      100 |                   |
 reducer.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.308s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/47704309